# separate fadeToggle divs with hashchange

Tags: jquery, hashchange

I got hashchange example and need to fadeToggle divs on link click. If link1 clicked fade in content1 div, if link2 fade in content2 and so on. Fade in and out of div's must be independent. Now only link background is changed and all 4 divs are hidden.
How to accomplish this with code that i have here: http://jsfiddle.net/fXA4z/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `click` method instead of listening to the `hashchnage` event:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')
    var which = this.href.slice(-1);
    $('div[class^="content"]').hide();
    $('div.content'+which).show()
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fXA4z/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but i also need hashchange function. Functional mypage.com/#link1 kind of links. And divs should fadeIn/fadeOut independently. When one is opened it shouldnt be closed when other is clicked